# Strange case of CS0029 (type mismatch) with switch statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Following code fails with the CS0029 error. Indeed this code is wrong - you should either start with tuple and have cases for tuples, or start with single variable and match on strings. The question is what compiler actually tries to do and why it accepts `switch (s1,s2)` as valid part of `switch` statement.

> CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to '(string s1, string s2)'

```
string s1 = "a", s2 = "b";

switch (s1,s2)
{
    case "a": //CS0029 
        Console.WriteLine("A"); 
        break; 
    default: break;
}
```

Variants that I expect to work (meaning it compiles and code in `case` runs):

tuple (braces around the tuple for the switch's syntax):

```
switch ((s1,s2)) {
   case ("a","b"):...
```

or single variable:

```
switch(s1) {
   case "a":
```

And one that I don't really expect to work but it does (which is what error message suggests essentially) - this case compiles and at run-time `case` code is executed (same way as `switch ((s1,s2))`):

```
switch (s1,s2) {
   case ("a","b"):...
```

Based on behavior and the error it looks like `switch (s1,s2)` is treated as `switch ((s1,s2))` but it is unclear why based on docs for [the switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1283-the-switch-statement)'

> switch_statement
> : 'switch' '(' expression ')' switch_block
> ;

---

<sub>Inspired by currently deleted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71803871</sub>

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do here? What is `case "a":` **intended** to mean? When both `s1` and `s2` are `"a"`, or just `s1`?

Comment: When you say "..don't really expect it to work but it does..", do you mean you receive some sort of output or mean you get a runtime error?

Comment: @Dai the code is clearly invalid and `switch(s1) { case "a":...` is what I likely would mean to write  in this case. As I said the question is due to trying to understand (now deleted) SO question - I don't understand the exact reason why that code compiles that far - I expect it to fail on `switch` line instead. I'm happy that I can write `switch (s1,s2)` when suitable but like to know why.

Comment: @DennisVW - updated. Compiles and runs and matches `case` as tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Your code here:

```
switch (s1,s2) {
   case ("a","b"):...
```

is compiled into this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    (string, string) tuple2 = ("a", "b");
    if (tuple2 == ("a", "b"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}
```

The reason for this is the native `switch` instruction of CIL `switch <uint32, int32, int32 (t1..tN)>`. In the creation of a jump table a pair of values (s1,s2) must be considered a single value `N` if both must equal a specified value for the `case` to be the target jump. This means the compiler interprets this as a `tuple` because the jump table cannot work otherwise.

---

EDIT:

You actually get some interesting results if you mess with it a bit. For instance

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s1 = "a";
            string s2 = "b";
            string s3 = "a";
            string s4 = "b";
            string s5 = "a";
            string s6 = "b";
            string s7 = "a";
            string s8 = "b";
            string s9 = "a";
            string s10 = "b";

            switch ((s1,s2),(s3,s4),s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10)
            {
                case (("a", "b"), ("a", "b"), "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"): 
                    Console.WriteLine("A");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

will compile into this absolute mess:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str3 = "a";
    string str5 = "a";
    ((string, string), (string, string), string, string, string, string, string, (string)) tuple = (("a", "b"), (str3, "b"), str5, "b", "a", "b", "a", ("b"));
    if (tuple.Item1 == ("a", "b"))
    {
        (string, string) tuple3 = tuple.Item2;
        if (((((((tuple3 == ("a", "b")) && (tuple.Item3 == "a")) && (tuple.Item4 == "b")) && (tuple.Item5 == "a")) && (tuple.Item6 == "b")) && (tuple.Item7 == "a")) && (tuple.Rest == ))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }
}
```

The primary reason for the compiler doing this is to allow for simplified syntax and to catch issues where the code will seek too many different targets. When a `switch` statement is used the compiler will create a series of if statements if it can accomplish this reasonably. Yes, your `switch` statement probably serves no purpose in terms of CPU time, but it does make it easier to read. The real issue is when the compiler is forced to make a jump table, which it cannot make as effective with more than one expression to compare the targets to. The easy way around this is to limit the number of items in the expression to a single object or as few objects as possible. Tuples allow the compiler to make your input into a single variable, or just a few variables limiting the number of if statements needed and drastically improving performance if a jump table is made.

---

EDIT December 2022:

It appears the compiler now starts adding guard clauses to this scenario as well if using a `when` expression in the switch statement. Probably not too important but it may prevent your `default` from running if something is null.

```
        string caseSwitch = "a";
        string caseSwitch2 = "b";
        switch ((caseSwitch, caseSwitch2))
        {
            case (string, string) myVar when myVar.Equals(("a","b")):
                break;
            case (string, string) myVar when myVar.Equals(("b","a")):
                break;
            case (string, string) myVar when myVar.Item1.Equals("a"):
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

now compiles to the C# code:

```
        string item = "a";
        string item2 = "b";
        ValueTuple<string, string> valueTuple = new ValueTuple<string, string>(item, item2);
        ValueTuple<string, string> valueTuple2 = valueTuple;
        string item3 = valueTuple2.Item1;
        if (item3 == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        string item4 = valueTuple2.Item2;
        if (item4 == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        ValueTuple<string, string> valueTuple3 = valueTuple2;
        if (valueTuple3.Equals(new ValueTuple<string, string>("a", "b")))
        {
            return;
        }
        ValueTuple<string, string> valueTuple4 = valueTuple2;
        if (!valueTuple4.Equals(new ValueTuple<string, string>("b", "a")))
        {
            ValueTuple<string, string> valueTuple5 = valueTuple2;
            if (valueTuple5.Item1.Equals("a"))
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify why `switch (s1,s2)` is not a syntax error? I don't see "because there CIL instruction" as good reason why it should compile into one in the first place...

Comment: Oh, you wanted to know why does it work? Its a different version of `var _s = ("a","b");` followed by `switch (_s)`. The compiler's job is to make your life as easy as possible. A tuple by definition is a data structure that holds multiple values of different variables. It is intended to be used to replace an object where creating an entire object type would be more complicated than necessary. When the compiler detects you making this "syntax error" it assumes you are trying to create a tuple because the expression in the `switch` statement matches the tuple structure.

Comment: Remember, a `switch` statement is intended to consider a series of single values `N` where `N` contains the target to jump to. Therefore any expression within the statement should be a single target. A tuple is a single target, and so is a string, but two strings is two targets and would either result in a verbose `if` chain that the runtime would struggle to minimize or an un-targetable mess of a jump table that the runtime would likely fail in.

Comment: added an edit in hopes it helps more